# Integrate keypress events into jQuery functions for accessibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to optimise my jQuery functions on a recently built site for accessibility, for instance quite a few functions I used either have a `hover` or `mouseover` event as the main event listener, but to make these sections fully accessibly via keyboard ideally they need to have an keypress/keyup trigger also.

I've seen a few examples of people using keypress then wrapping the function in an if statement to match it to the enter key, but this will then disable any other trigger.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can integrate the keypress into my simple `mouseover` event below for example:

```
$('.insight-featured').on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().children('.hover-frame').css({"opacity" : '1', "scale" : "1"})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sticking to jquery, you can handle it by just having a single event handler:

```js
function handleTheThing (e) {
  if (e.keyCode !== undefined && e.keyCode !== 13) {
    return;
  }

  $(this).css({ color: "red" });
}

$("#test").on("mouseover", handleTheThing);
$("#test").on("keydown", handleTheThing);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Here is a thing</button>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that would work well if I just had one function in my jquery file, otherwise I'd have to create that function 10 times over for each function in my js file

Comment: @SamStAubyn I'm not sure I follow; why would you have to create the same function 10 times over?